# weird behaviour when using 'em' and percentage

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-size

I'm building a responsive site and I'd like to use [new css3 unit - rem](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) for it.

I've set the base font-size on the html tag to be `1rem` which is `16px` and then set the body to be 62.5% which supposed to be `10px` but when looking at the computed styles in chrome console, I see the body `font-size:12px`.

I tried setting the body using `0.625em` but still the same result, what am I missing?

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pPmBm/2/

I on Firefox and it seems to be working fine, so it seems like a chrome problem.

Comment: Hi, I just checked your jsfidle and it looked OK: HTML has a 16px font size, body overrides that to 62,5%, and the body has a 10px font size as expected.

Comment: I don't see any rems or ems in your fiddle. Did you link the wrong one?

Comment: Note that a rem value takes after the font size of `html` no matter what unit of measurement you set to it, so if `html` is 16px, then 1rem is always equal to 16px.

Comment: NO, but the point is that even before i start using any font-size, i can't get the body to be the right size, anyway i've updated the fiddle

Comment: I'm using Chrome 23/winXP and the jsfiddle has the correct size: 10px. Of course, you are not using yet the rem units.

Comment: Not related: in jsFiddle your are supposed to put only the body content inside the HTML panel and all the css in the css panel. updated here http://jsfiddle.net/pPmBm/3/ . I still see 10px, its really weird that you see a different size.

Comment: I actually went and change the actual size to `font-size:10px` and still in the computed styles tab, i see `font-size:12px` so i guess it a bug in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never worked with `rem` before, but looking at the site you linked, it seems like you flipped it around:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 1rem; } /* =10px */
```

Comment: I tried it any way you want, but i keep seeing `font-size:12px`, look at the example i posted and play with it, see if you can get to 10px.

Comment: It looks like a bug in chrom, when i look in the computed style tab i see `font-size:12px' even on the div defined as `10px` so i guess the actuall size is 10px and its just a glitch.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.45 beta-m, everything seems fine in my computed style tab.

Comment: mine is Version 23.0.1271.97 m, so i guess i should upgrade.